# Best service/SDK to test connection speed from a browser to an AWS EC2 instance

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, udp, speed-test

I am working on a project where a user would connect to an AWS Ec2 instance using most probably UDP and I was wondering what the best service would be to test the network performance of an user connecting to the instance from the browser, from a Web page.
An example of my requirement would be the [ping test](https://thegamingproject.co/pingtest) by The Gaming Project.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S: I am not very sure what the best tag to give for this, so I've given all that stackoverflow suggested.

Edit: I forgot to add that I need to do it from a website.

Comment: What is the actual problem to be solved here? Just ping the EC2 instance or open a port and calculate the time it takes to return a response? This will depend on the application being hosted on the EC2 instance

Comment: I forgot to add that I need to do it from a website. Have edited the post. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If this is about bandwidth, have a look at this discussion:

https://superuser.com/questions/1275043/measure-bandwidth-between-two-computer-in-a-lan

There are a few tools that can help you measure the bandwidth between any two computers, e.g iPerf, which apparently also allows you to measure UDP connections.
Haven't tested it myself, but it looks promising...

Comment: Hey, I forgot to add that I need to do it from a website. So is there some library or something that I can use for testing this?